# Default member type can be changed by constructor?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a class `A` with a member `m`.
I wanted the member variable to have a default (derived) type, but which could optionally be changed in the class constructor to another (derived) type. 
Something like

```cpp
// A.h
class A
{
    DefaultType m {0};
};


// A.cpp
A::A()
{
    // if this is present, change m
    m = OtherType(1., 2.);

    // otherwise, leave as default
}
```

Sorry I wasn't very clear the first time, tried to simplify the question and may have made it unintelligible.
The context is that I'm exposing the constructor of `A` to the user, which is supposed to write the constructor, compile the code and run it. The rest of the implementation of `A` is in a separate file, not user-accessible. Some of the member functions of `A` defined there will need to access `m.fun()`, which is a common method to `DefaultType` and `OtherType`.

So the constraint is that I want the syntax within the constructor to be as simple as possible.
If the user writes the constructor but simply leaves out the (re)definition of `m`, then the program will just consider it to be of the default type, and use `.fun()` from that class. Otherwise, `m` will be of `OtherType` and `.fun()` will come from there.

Added to this, there will be some 10 other members like `m`.
I wanted to know if something like this is possible or if I'll have to rethink the whole design.

Comment: Is it assignable to the field's declared type?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve by doing something like this? Please read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Isn't that just a `std::unique_ptr<BaseType>`?

Comment: And perhaps you should get [a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and read more about *inheritance* and *polymorphism*?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I may have fallen right into the XY problem trap, I'm sorry. Thank you for the references.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
class Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class DefaultType : public Base
{
};

class OtherType : public Base
{
};

class A
{
public:
    A(bool use_default = true)
    {
        if (use_default)
            m.reset(new DefaultType());
        else
            m.reset(new OtherType());
    }
    std::unique_ptr<Base> m;
};
```